# In python (globals())[method](param1,param2) the same as exec('method(param1,param2)?

Tags: python-3.x

In python...
`(globals())[method](param1,param2)`

The same as...
`exec('method(param1,param2)')`

Both methods from my understanding result to the same invocation of the method.  I can't see any specific benefit of one technique versus the other?  Any hidden pitfalls with either that would suggest one over the other?  Does the interpreter design or best practice suggest one over the other?

Comment: as a rule of thumb, _never ever_ use `exec()` if you have another feasible option, because if your input to it is in _any way_ dynamic then there's the possibility of arbitrary code execution (and also leads to situations very difficult to debug and harder code to read). In this case, one way they would maybe differ is if `method` in the local scope shadowed a different `method` in the global scope, or the same for `param1` or `param2`.

Comment: Best practice *suggest to use neither*

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, well, that is not an option, in all cases, otherwise the 'methods' to execute data as code would not exist.  There are specific times when you don't want to write static logic into code.  For example, value driven tables, that require unique callbacks based on the values in said table.   You can't always write deterministic code that is exhaustive in validation or context, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The snippet

```
(globals())[method](param1,param2)
```

accesses a key `method` from the dictionary `globals()` (one look-up) and executes the returned value as a callable passing to it the arguments `param1` and `param2`.

The snippet

```
exec('method(param1,param2)')
```

does a lot more under the hood, since it needs to parse the string as an [abstract syntax tree](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html), access `method`, `param1` and `param2` in the dictionary `globals()` (three look-ups) and execute the `method` as a callable passing `param1` and `param2` to it.

Comment: Ah, so the execution 'cost' (if not complexity) is different.  That works for me.  Thanks.